# CubeCamera.js rendering black/nothing

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've tried practically everything and the code seems to be perfectly valid. I've tried changing the threejs version, changing from MeshPhongMaterial to MeshBasicMaterial and back, and tried copy pasting code from online. However I still get the same result. CubeCamemra.js works perfectly for me on this ->> http://blog.romanliutikov.com/post/58910953451/dynamic-reflections-in-three-js, but when I try to implement it locally, it renders black. Please tell me if I am missing anything important. Thanks in advance!

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
camera.position.z = 5;
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
var cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera(0.1, 1000, 256); // parameters: near, far, resolution
cubeCamera.renderTarget.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter; // mipmap filter

scene.add(cubeCamera);


var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 30, 30),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    envMap: cubeCamera.renderTarget,
    color: 0x00ffff
  })
);
//sphere.position.y = 3;
scene.add(sphere);
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1),new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
scene.add(cube);
cube.position.y = 3;
function render() {

  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  sphere.visible = false;
  cubeCamera.updateCubeMap(renderer, scene);
  sphere.visible = true;

  renderer.render(scene,camera);

  controls.update();

}
render();
```

http://puu.sh/aqcib/6c2b15d6ca.png -- pic of whats happening

Comment: The problem is the `cubeCamera`, here is a [**working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GDXcJ/2/) with your code (cubeCamera commented)

Comment: What I think you are missing is that your example code has no environment to render (the white page is just the default browser page I think, unseen by WebGL). No background = no reflection map. No reflection map = darkness.

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cosmonia/GDXcJ/3/) is a working fiddle with cubeCamera reflecting, I just had to use a much older (r54) version of threejs instead of (r61)

Comment: And we are at r68 so you should really move to that.